# Number of equivalence relations on a set

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

If a set has $n$ elements then what are maximum number of equivalence classes and equivalence relations possible on it?

Answer (score 7):

The maximum number of equivalence classes is $n$ -the identity relation $\{ (x,x) \ | \ x \in X \}$ is an equivalence relation.  The number of equivalence relations is the [Bell number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_numbers).  The series is in [A000110 of OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000110).

Comment: the empty relation is not an equivalence relation (except on the empty set!).  I think you meant to say "identity relation".  Anyway, I'm sure we are both talking about the relation whose ordered pairs are $(x,x)$ for all $x \in X$.

Comment: @Pete:  fixed.  Thanks.  Also added the OEIS reference

Comment: it looks like there was some kind of strange edit conflict which caused part of your edit to be undone.  Since we agree on the content, I went ahead and fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

The Stirling numbers of the second kind $S(n,k)$ are by definition the number of ways you can partition some set of $n$ elements into $k$ non-empty and disjoint subsets. But since an equivalence relation may partition your set into any amount of subsets, you need to sum over all possibilities:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n S(n,k)$$

gives you the anwser.

You can read about them [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)